# Failure to save uploaded txt file in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-uploads

I'm new to flask. I'm trying to take user import and save it in the backend. I failed to save the file (I couldn't see uploaded file in static), hence couldn't read from file. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks.

Error: *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/uploadsDB/Reviews.txt'*

**My app.py:**

```
#flask packages
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap 
from flask_uploads import UploadSet,configure_uploads,IMAGES,DATA,ALL

#systems
import os 
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import spacy

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
#db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Configuration for File Uploads
files = UploadSet('files',ALL)
app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST'] = 'static/uploadsDB'
configure_uploads(app,files)

# Spacy packages
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'txt_data' in request.files:
        num_sentences = request.form['num_sentences']
        file = request.files['txt_data']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        # os.path.join is used so that paths work in every operating system
        # file.save(os.path.join("wherever","you","want",filename))
        file.save(os.path.join('static/uploadsDB',filename))
        fullfile = os.path.join('static/uploadsDB',filename)
        text_file = open(os.path.join('static/uploadsDB',filename), "r").read()
        nlp_file_doc = nlp(text_file)
        sentences = list(nlp_file_doc.sents)
        return render_template('annotation.html', sentences = sentences)
```

**My index.html:**

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="main">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color:#ecb164">
                  <h3 style="color:#fff">Step 1: Upload your dataset</h3>
                    <p style="color:#fff">This tool only accept <ins>txt</ins> format text data </p>
                    <p style="color:#fff">Every sentence should either separate with punctuation or  </p>
                      <form method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="file" name="txt_data">
                          <h3 style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255)">Step 2: Input lines of sentences you have processed</h3>
                            <p style="color:#fff"> Please enter 0 if this is your first attempt </p>
                        <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="num_sentences" value=0>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file does not get saved in the first place.

This is the problematic line:

`file.save(os.path.join('static/uploadsDB',filename))`

Here, `file` refers to the form data, but as you use `Flask-Uploads` or its successor [Flask-Reuploaded](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/) the `UploadSet` is taking care of saving a file.

And you named your `UploadSet` **files**.

Also, as you have configured the path were to save the files already ( `app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST'] = 'static/uploadsDB'` ) you do not need to repeat this information again.

So, in order to save the file, you only have to use the following code:

```
files.save(file)
```

The `save` method of an `UploadSet` also takes an argument `name`.

If you wish to give the saved file an arbitrary name, you can write ...

```
files.save(file, name="some_name")
```

If you want to learn more about `Flask-Reuploaded` you can always have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/master/src/flask_uploads/flask_uploads.py).

You can also learn more about the used data structures for the form results in the [werkzeug documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage).